# How to prevent pandas datafram columns from moving to new line in colab?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working in colab and created a dataframe using this code:

```
def daily_sma():
  symbol = 'BTCUSDT'
  num_bars = 70 
  timeframe = '1d' 
  bars = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe = timeframe, limit = num_bars) 

  df_d = pd.DataFrame(bars, columns = ['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
  df_d['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_d['timestamp'], unit = 'ms') 
  df_d['sma20_d'] = df_d.close.rolling(20).mean()
  df_d = df_d.dropna()

  return df_d
```

But when I get and print it it does something like:

```
timestamp      open      high       low     close        volume       \
19 2022-09-29  19412.82  19645.52  18843.01  19591.51  406424.93256   
20 2022-09-30  19590.54  20185.00  19155.36  19422.61  444322.95340   
21 2022-10-01  19422.61  19484.00  19159.42  19310.95  165625.13959   
22 2022-10-02  19312.24  19395.91  18920.35  19056.80  206812.47032   
23 2022-10-03  19057.74  19719.10  18959.68  19629.08  293585.75212   

       sma20_d  
19  19795.5145  
20  19684.2280  
21  19558.4320  
22  19391.4850  
23  19364.2605
```

One column is below the rest of the table even though there is enough space in the console. How can I place this column next to the volume column so it can be more readable.

I have tried to decrease the width between columns but it makes no difference.

```
pd.options.display.width = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `print` with [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
print(df.to_string())

# to set a larger, yet not unlimited width
# print(df.to_string(line_width=200))
```

If you want a permanent change, defined in terms of number of characters:

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)
print(df)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'column_{x}' for x in range(10)], index=range(3))

print(df)

print('\n\n# with to_string()')
print(df.to_string())

print('\n\n# with option')
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  column_0 column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4 column_5 column_6 column_7  \
0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
2      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   

  column_8 column_9  
0      NaN      NaN  
1      NaN      NaN  
2      NaN      NaN  


# with to_string()
  column_0 column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4 column_5 column_6 column_7 column_8 column_9
0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN


# with option
  column_0 column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4 column_5 column_6 column_7 column_8 column_9
0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```